# PLESK, Rails App : ExecJS::RuntimeUnavailable: Could not find a JavaScript runtime

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this bug that I can't solve...

Here is my Gemfile :

```
gem 'therubyracer', group: :assets
gem 'execjs'
```

When I'm on Plesk, 'bundle install' works perfectly, but when I run rake task : db:migrate
It fails with this error :

```
/var/www/vhosts/monegliseaparis.fr/votes.monegliseaparis.fr/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.3/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/duplicable.rb:111: warning: BigDecimal.new is deprecated; use BigDecimal() method instead.
rake aborted!
ExecJS::RuntimeUnavailable: Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/rails/execjs for a list of available runtimes.
/var/www/vhosts/monegliseaparis.fr/votes.monegliseaparis.fr/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/execjs-2.8.1/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:58:in `autodetect'
/var/www/vhosts/monegliseaparis.fr/votes.monegliseaparis.fr/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/execjs-2.8.1/lib/execjs.rb:5:in `'
/var/www/vhosts/monegliseaparis.fr/votes.monegliseaparis.fr/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/execjs-2.8.1/lib/execjs.rb:4:in `'
/var/www/vhosts/monegliseaparis.fr/votes.monegliseaparis.fr/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/uglifier-4.2.0/lib/uglifier.rb:5:in `require'
/var/www/vhosts/monegliseaparis.fr/votes.monegliseaparis.fr/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/uglifier-4.2.0/lib/uglifier.rb:5:in `'
/var/www/vhosts/monegliseaparis.fr/votes.monegliseaparis.fr/config/application.rb:8:in `'
/var/www/vhosts/monegliseaparis.fr/votes.monegliseaparis.fr/Rakefile:4:in `require'
/var/www/vhosts/monegliseaparis.fr/votes.monegliseaparis.fr/Rakefile:4:in `'
/var/www/vhosts/monegliseaparis.fr/votes.monegliseaparis.fr/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/exe/rake:27:in `'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```